# FPS Drops After Some Draw Cycle

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am drawing Textured Square when we tapped the screen. I am using the same texture. After some tapping the FPS drops to around 4 from 120 in New ios Devices. I am passing the point where i tapped and size of the texture and texture to the shader every time when finger tapped.

Any optimized way to this scenario

Comment: Check the Xcode GPU Capture Tools to find the GPU cost

Comment: Is the problem that the CPU seems to be throttled? Take a look at this SO question for a description and source code that shows the problem with a Metal example app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727578/ios-11-cpu-throttling-and-idle-timer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have something that is accumulating work on the main application thread. Check what you are doing in your tap actions. Maybe something is getting added to a loop somewhere that is executing on the main thread.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/DO3zbvQ This is the simple Image. Here You can see If i add thousand points anyway thousands draw functions are accumulating. How to avoid that.